# can't pass keyvaluePair to my webservice

Tags: json, web-services, keyvaluepair

I have web service like follows:

```
void uploadUserProperty(KeyValuePair<string, string[]> properties, string userId);
```

when I pass the right json to the web service, i always got 400 bad request.
but if the web service change to:

```
void uploadUserProperty(string properties, string userId);
```

I can correct use the web service.
I'm sure the json i pass to the webservice is right.
Can anyone help?

Comment: This does not look java to me. Which language is this?

Comment: I'm using c# and this is based on wcf